# Comparacion en archivo bat cmd

Tags: cmd, batch, if

Estoy intentando hacer una comparación utilizando el IF() en donde comparo el mes actual y le asigno su nombre
pero no logro imprimir los resultados de las variables

Este es el código que tengo

```
@echo off
SET FOLDER=%Date:~0,2%-%Date:~3,2%-%Date:~6,4%-%time:~0,2%
set mes=%date:~3,2%
@echo %mes%
set nombre="nombre"


IF %mes% == 10 (
    %nombre%="Octubre"  
    @echo %nombre%
)
if %mes% == 11 (
    %nombre%="Noviembre"
    @echo %nombre%
)

pause
```

Al final me da un mensaje como este:

> ""nombre"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>   "nombre"

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: @PatricioMoracho te comento que agregandole el set a esas lineas me imprime el texto "nombre"

Comment: @PatricioMoracho realize los cambios que me mencionaste y se quito el mensaje que me mostraba... pero ahora ya no me imprime nada... no me esta guardando las variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que las variables de entorno en los archivos batch se "expanden" cuando se analiza una línea. En el caso de los bloques delimitados por paréntesis  el bloque entero cuenta como una "línea" o comando.

Una posibilidad es que el `echo` o el uso que hagas de la variable lo hagas afuera de los bloques `if`:

```
set mes=%date:~3,2%
set nombre="nombre"

IF %mes% == 10 (
    set nombre="Octubre"  
)
```

Otra posibilidad es usar `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` y acceder a la variable mediante `!`, lo cual fuerza la evaluación de la misma:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set mes=%date:~3,2%
set nombre="nombre"

IF %mes% == 10 (
    set nombre="Octubre"  
    @echo !nombre!
)
```

Fuente: [Variables in batch file not being set when inside IF?](https://superuser.com/questions/78496/variables-in-batch-file-not-being-set-when-inside-if)